# What do I have to use "I had to" or "I have to"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-simple

What is the difference between the following 2 sentences.

The first:

```
To solve the problem I have to create a new file.
```

The second:

```
To solve the problem I had to create a new file.
```

The context where the sentence must be written is: "I have already found a solution of a problem, and I'm describing the steps needed by this solution".

Is more correct the use of the past (`I had to`) or the present (`I have to`)?

---

**EDIT:** I have written this question because I was thinking about a translation provided by `google translate` and in this case Google was right because it has used the past while, in my text, I have used the present.
Sometimes google translate provides translations not correct so, before making corrections on my text, I have written this question.

Comment: Are you describing the way you _will_ solve the problem, or the way you have _already_ solved it?

Comment: @Kate Bunting I have already solved the problem so the right sentence I think is `To solve the problem I had to create a new file.` Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: [Please note the question form in English: What **do I have to use** etc.,? not what I have to use]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you I have changed it in the title. I'm here to learning English :)

Comment: I understand. Here's another one for you. :) Learning English is fun. I'm here to learn English.  Your question is "had" since you have **already** done it.

Comment: A translation. Please check your nouns.

Comment: (translate ---> translation) OK correct it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To solve the problem I have to create a new file.

Means you are doing it **now** or will do before the problem is solved.

> To solve the problem I had to create a new file.

Means you already did it **sometime in the past**. Simple examples of present and past tenses.

Comment: Could you explain me a possible reason because someone has downvoted my question. If I understood that, in the future I'll avoid to make question not suited for this Site. Thank you

Comment: @User051209 Only the person who downvoted can explain, but here is my best guess: you did not say why you thought the present tense could be correct, and you did not say what research you did before asking the question.